# Multiple Flv Component playback - through a for loop - rewind issues AS3 Flash CS4

Tags: flash-cs4

I am building a "video wall" app in flash AS3. I am importing a movie clip with a flvPlayback component nested within, then Adding it to the display list 12 times in a for loop (which is based on the length of an xml file.) The xml file aslo points to the .source of the flv instance.

This method is working, for displaying video content on all screens BUT, it only loops the last flvPlayback component. The rest just go back to the first frame of the video.

```
var vidURL = vidXML.video_item[i].@url  
SS.video.source = vidURL;
SS.video.autoRewind = true;
SS.video.autoPlay = true;
SS.video.addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE, Loop);

function Loop(event:VideoEvent):void
{
     SS.video.play();
}
```

I have tried refering to the SS + [i] to call the event to rewind as soon as it happens (as the videos are different lengths) but have had no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Jono

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry chaps...
using the "event.target.play()" is triggered when each video finishes, and rewinds them all nicely.

Sorry.

Jono